# Is such a polynomial coefficient possible?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Suppose we have a polynomial $(x+y)^2$. What I noticed is that if you subtract $4xy,$ the result changes to $(x-y)^2$.
$(x+y)^2 - 4xy = x^2 + 2xy+ y^2 - 4xy = x^2-2xy+y^2 = (x-y)^2.$

This has me thinking about the flexibility of changing that sum just by adding or subtraction coefficients of $xy.$

So, my question is, does there exist nonzero coefficients $b, c, d \in \mathbb{C}$ such that
$$b(x+y)^2 + cxy = d(x+y)^2?$$

I don't know why, but for some reason I have this mental roadblock about analyzing multivariate polynomials. The answer seems like "no" by equating coefficients and deriving a contradiction, but on the other hand there's numbers like the golden ratio that satisfy $1 + \frac{1}{\phi} = \phi$ and so maybe there's two specific non-zero numbers where such a postulation is possible.

Comment: Check for typos.  Did you want any minuses in what you wrote?  Otherwise, $b(x+y)^2 + cxy = d(x+y)^2$ is true for $b=d$ and $c=0$

Comment: I did intend a minus in the first sentence. But is there any non-zero $c$ this is true for?

Comment: Note that two polynomials are equal iff each of their respective coefficients are equal.  The coefficient of $x^2$ in the expansion on the left is $b$ and the coefficient of $x^2$ in the expansion on the right is $d$, so these must be equal.

Comment: If you simplify the left-hand side you obtain a $(2b+c)xy$ term, is there anything that can be done with that for non-zero $c$?

Comment: You can [edit] the question to show us your work equating coefficients and ask if there's any gap in your logic. Your concluding true statement about the golden mean doesn't seem to point to a problem.

Comment: Again... fix your question to have whatever minus you intended to have.  As it stands, $b(x+y)^2+cxy=d(x+y)^2$, by equating polynomials would have you see by comparing coefficients that $b=d$.  Subtracting $b(x+y)^2$ from both sides then leaves you with $cxy=0$ which again by comparing coefficients leads you to $c=0$.  If you had $b(x-y)^2+cxy=d(x+y)^2$ instead, the same process can be used of comparing coefficients, leading you to $b=d$ and $c = 4b$

Comment: Okay, when I compare coefficients, the first thing I see is $b=d,$ so far so good, we agree. Now, the next thing I see is $2b+c = d$ by the middle terms on both sides, leading me to $b = 2b+c,$ $-b = c.$

Comment: Expand and compare coefficients on both left and right sides. $bx^2 + by^2 + (2b + c) xy = dx^2 + dy^2 + 2dxy$.

Comment: $2b + c \ne d$. Rather $2b + c = 2d$

Comment: You are correct, I made a typo. Guess the answer is "no".

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no by the method of equating coefficients as discussed in the comments.

Upon expanding both sides, we obtain

$bx^2 + 2bxy + by^2 + cxy = dx^2 + 2dxy + dy^2.$

$bx^2 + (2b+c)xy+by^2 = dx^2 + 2dxy + dy^2.$

Equating coefficients, one may first find $b=d,$ then $2b+c = 2d \implies c=0.$